# Formatar valor com explode e implode PHP

Tags: php, data

Possuo uma tag dhEmi que possui este valor `2016-09-09T08:10:52-03:00`

Para me retornar uma datetime fiz o seguinte.

```
$dtemis = $item->infNFe->ide->dhEmi;

$res = explode("T", $dtemis);
$res1 = explode("-03:00", $res[1]);

$array = array ($res[0],$res1[0]);
$dtemisformat = implode (' ', $array);

$dtemisformat = ''.$dtemisformat.'.000';
```

O código acima me retorna `2016-09-09 08:10:52.000` porém o valor ***-03:00*** na linha `$res1 = explode("-03:00", $res[1]);` vária, não sendo sempre o mesmo por exemplo: ***-02:00***.

Há alguma sugestão para melhorar o código ?

Comment: Qual é o objetivo desse código, apenas a hora?

Comment: A data e a hora é que após isso dou um insert no banco. Então preciso formatar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse formato de data é `ISO8601 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO";` então, não precisa usar [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) ou/e [implode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php), use a [classe DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.format.php) que vai solucionar o seu problema:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:sO' , '2016-09-09T08:10:52-03:00' );
```

e após isso você pode formatar de maneira eficiente assim:

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Como você está ignorando a ultima parte não vejo necessidade de colocar **000**.

Comment: Entendi, tinha esquecido do `DateTime`.

Comment: Sem problemas @Kevin.F, o importante é dá uma melhor experiência para os usuários e ajudar é sempre bom.

Answer (score 5):

É mais simples deixar essa tarefa com uma função/classe especializada. Esse formatado de data é conhecido como [W3C](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.w3c), para pegar parte da data use a classe DateTime e o método `format()`

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::W3C, '2016-09-09T08:10:52-03:00');
echo $d->format('H:i:s');
```